# File upload using Express and multer

Tags: html, node.js, express, file-upload

I can't seem to get multer to work no matter what I do; I've read everything I could find on the matter, and as far as examples go--I've followed them to the best of my ability.

[Here is a JSFiddle link to my work](https://jsfiddle.net/hmr9Lsq7/3/).

I can never seem to get the file to upload, despite it actually uploading. In my code, I have

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
  console.log("____ Clicked submit ____");
  console.log(req.body);

  console.dir(req.files);
});
```

The `req.body.attachment` will show the filename I attached. However, `req.files` returns `undefined`.

I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `multer` handler somewhere in your middleware chain. You have defined the handler with:

```
var upload = multer({
  dest: './tmp/'
});
```

But, you do not use it in your middleware chain.

There are two options: 
1) Use a global handler (top of the chain, not recommended) 
2) Use it on your `submit` route (recommended)

Read the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for specific implementation, but the following should work.

```
// Multer parses single field "attachment"
app.post('/submit', upload.single('attachment'), function(req, res) {
  console.log("____ Clicked submit ____");
  console.log(req.body);

  // console.dir(req.files);
  // for single field use `req.file`, not `req.files`
  console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: I had already tried this. I knew I was forgetting something--but this still yields `undefined`. would it possibly have to do with the script I use in my html at the very bottom?

Comment: Absolutely. You need to treat multipart requests differently over XHR. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: I was adding that extra script to stop the page from reloading upon submission of the form; how can I stop the page from reloading, while still handling the form stuff on the server?